# According to John 14:16-21, is Jesus the Comforter and Spirit of truth?

Tags: john, jesus, context

It appears that Jesus is speaking in third person because he states that he will send another comforter in v16 and then goes back to first person by saying that he will come to comfort the disciples in v18.

Comment: There are quite clearly two comforters.

Comment: @O.J. No! Jesus is doing the speaking and here is what He says at vs16. "And I will ask the Father, and He will give you "ANOTHER" Helper/the Holy Spirit or the "Paracletos." One called alongside to help.," that He may be with you forever." Vs17, "that is the Spirit of truth etc." So in this verse alone you have the three persons of the Trinity. Also look at John 14:23, "If anyone loves Me, he will keep My word; and My Father will love him, and "WE" will come to him, and make "OUR" abode with him." Another means: "being one more in addition to one or more of the same kind."

Comment: @NigelJ quite clearly NOT.

Answer (score 3):

> <sup>15</sup> “If you love me, you will keep my commandments. <sup>16</sup> And I will ask the Father, and he will give you another Helper, to be with you forever, <sup>17</sup> even the Spirit of truth, whom the world cannot receive, because it neither sees him nor knows him. You know him, for he dwells with you and will be in you. (John 14 ESV)

First, Jesus says He will ask the Father who will give the disciples **another** Helper. The Greek is *allos parakletos*. The promise of **another** *parakletos*, which the ESV translates as *Helper*, means the disciples must have already been given a Helper. That is, only after first having a Helper is **another** Helper possible. In his letter, John identifies the first as Jesus:

> My little children, I am writing these things to you so that you may not sin. But if anyone does sin, we have an Advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous. (1 John 2:1)

English translations obscure the fact "Helper" and "Advocate" are the same word, [παράκλητον](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g3875/kjv/tr/0-1/), *parakletos*; used only by John (cf. [John 14:16, 26, 15:26, 16:7, and 1 John 2:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2014%3A16%2C%2026%2C%2015%3A26%2C%2016%3A7%2C%201%20John%202%3A1&version=ESV)). Therefore, Jesus is the *parakletos* and the Spirit of Truth is *allos parakletos*. The term [*allos*](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g243/kjv/tr/0-1/) means another, but unlike [*heteros*](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g2087/kjv/tr/0-1/) which also means another, *allos* is another of the same type.

> and said to him, “Are you the one who is to come, or shall we look for another  [*ἕτερον, heteros*]?” (Matthew 11:3)

Jesus calls the *allos parakeltos*, the Spirit of Truth. The Greek is τὸ πνεῦμα τῆς ἀληθείας. Since truth is written with the article, a more precise rendering would be *the Spirit of the Truth*. The significance is Jesus is the Truth:

> <sup>6</sup> Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and **the truth**, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me. <sup>7</sup> If you had known me, you would have known my Father also. From now on you do know him and have seen him.” (John 14)

Just as Jesus is the *parakletos*, the *allos parakletos* is the Spirit of the Truth, which is Jesus. Therefore we have a clear description of co-equal nature of Jesus and the Spirit, both are *parakletos*, both are Truth. One is *parakleots* and Truth in the flesh; one is *allos parakletos* and Truth in Spirit.

Finally, if one knows Jesus as *parakletos* and the Truth, one then knows the Father as *parakletos* and Truth. The Father is able to sent *allos parakletos* who is the Spirit of the Truth since He is one with Jesus. Stated chronically we should say, just as the Father sent the *parakletos* who is the Truth who is Jesus who is one with the Father, Jesus who is the *parakletos* who is the Truth will ask the one who He is one with, the Father, to send *allos parakletos* who is the Spirit of the Truth. Thus showing the co-equality of the Three.

Comment: Matthew 10:19-20
New King James Version
19 "But when they deliver you up, do not worry about how or what you should speak. For it will be given to you in that hour what you should speak; 20 for it is not you who speak, but the Spirit of your Father who speaks in you.">>>> How many eternal spirits are within a believer?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore What does the Scripture say? *However, when He, the Spirit of truth, has come, He will guide you into all truth; for He will not speak on His own authority, but whatever He hears He will speak John 16:13)* So when the believer speaks the words given are the words the Father's, or the Son's, or the Spirit's, or the believer's?

Comment: You can rest assured that I have laid all these details out in a rational way in my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> It appears that Jesus is speaking in third person because he states
> that *he will send* another comforter in v16 ...

No, He does not say this.  The literal Greek text reads:

> καὶ ἐγὼ - And I
>  ἐρωτήσω τὸν πατέρα - will pray [to] the Father
> καὶ ἄλλον παράκλητον - and another Comforter
>  δώσει ὑμῖν - [He] will
> give to you

The subject of *will give* - δώσει (*dōsei*) - is the Father, not Jesus.

Comment: Thats very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Let there be no doubt that the NT refers to Jesus as the parakletos/comforter/helper/advocate:

> 1 John 2:1 - My little children, I am writing these things to you so
> that you will not sin. But if anyone does sin, **we have an advocate
> before the Father—Jesus Christ**, the Righteous One.

However, in the Gospel of John, Jesus refers to "***Another***" advocate/helper/comforter, namely the Holy Spirit who is also the "Spirit of Truth".

- John 14:16, 17 - And I will ask the Father, and He will give you **another Advocate** to be with you forever— the Spirit of truth. The world cannot receive Him, because it neither sees Him nor knows Him. But you do know Him, for He abides with you and will be in you.
- John 14:26 - But **the Advocate, the Holy Spirit**, whom the Father will send in My name, will teach you all things and will remind you of everything I have told you.
- John 15:26 - When **the Advocate** comes, whom I will send to you from the Father—the **Spirit of truth** who proceeds from the Father—He will testify about Me.
- John 16:7ff - But I tell you the truth, it is for your benefit that I am going away. Unless I go away, **the Advocate** will not come to you; but if I go, **I will send Him** to you.  **8** And when He comes, He will convict the world in regard to sin and righteousness and judgment: **9** in regard to sin, because they do not believe in Me; **10** in regard to righteousness, because I am going to the Father and you will no longer see Me; **11** and in regard to judgment, because the prince of this world has been condemned.  **12** I still have much to tell you, but you cannot yet bear to hear it. **13** However, when **the Spirit of truth** comes, He will guide you into all truth. For He will not speak on His own, but He will speak what He hears, and He will declare to you what is to come. **14** He will **glorify Me** by taking from what is Mine and disclosing it to you.

This final passage is quite significant - it tells us that the Holy Spirit is quite distinct from Jesus, and "another comforter", separate from Jesus, who would teach about Jesus.

Comment: Interesting take.  Jesus, his God and Father, and also an entirely separate mediator dwells with the children of God?  3 eternal spirits all dwelling with us.... This certainly begs the question as to function of this new separate spiritual person when our Master tells us he and his father already dwell with us.   Can you elaborate a bit more as to the function of each of these spirits within a child of God?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - I suggest you ask another question.  However, for the present, see John 16.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, Jesus is not speaking in the third person in v16. Just as pronouns are used to distinguish between persons or groups of people in English, the pronouns in Jn 14:16-18 identify three persons who act in relation to the “you” who are Jesus' disciples.

> And **I** will pray to the Father, and **He** will give you another
> Helper, that **He** may abide with you forever... **He** dwells with
> you and will be in you. 18 **I** will not leave you orphans; **I** will
> come to you. – Jn 14:16-18 NKJV

We have “he” (the Father) who gives, “He” (the Helper/Comforter) who abides/dwells, and “I” (Jesus) who comes. While the persons are distinct, their actions are much less so. The Father gives the Helper, but it is Jesus who comes. Given this flow in the narrative, it is natural to question, as the OP does, whether Jesus is the same person as the Helper.

In my opinion, the changes from first person to third person pronouns actually help to keep the persons separate. For comparison, in Jn 15:26 it is the Helper who comes and Jesus who sends. The pronouns “He” and “I/Me” help us to distinguish between them.

> But when the Helper comes, whom **I** shall send to you from the Father,
> the Spirit of truth who proceeds from the Father, **He** will testify of
> Me – John 15:26

In these as well as other verses in chapters 14 to 16 of John, the ambiguity that exists lies less in the pronouns than in how the actions appear to parallel one another. In Jn 16:14-15, for instance, it is difficult to narrow the act of declaring down to any one person.

> For **He** will take of what is **Mine** and declare it to you. 15 All
> things that the Father has are **Mine**. Therefore **I** said that
> **He** will take of **Mine** and declare it to you. - Jn 16:14-15

Again, while the pronouns help to differentiate between the persons, they do not help to distinguish between their actions. In the gospel of John, it appears to me that there are three persons who for all intent and purposes work together as one.

Answer (score 0):

John 14:16-26 ESV

The key passages are bolded.
The whole passage is quoted for context.

> **16 And I will ask the Father, and he will give you another Helper,
> to be with you forever, 17 even the Spirit of truth, whom the world
> cannot receive, because it neither sees him nor knows him. You know
> him, for he dwells with you and will be in you.**
>
> 18 “I will not leave you as orphans; I will come to you. 19 Yet a
> little while and the world will see me no more, but you will see me.
> Because I live, you also will live. 20 In that day you will know that
> I am in my Father, and you in me, and I in you. 21 Whoever has my
> commandments and keeps them, he it is who loves me. And he who loves
> me will be loved by my Father, and I will love him and manifest myself
> to him.” 22 Judas (not Iscariot) said to him, “Lord, how is it that
> you will manifest yourself to us, and not to the world?” 23 Jesus
> answered him, “If anyone loves me, he will keep my word, and my Father
> will love him, and we will come to him and make our home with him. 24
> Whoever does not love me does not keep my words. And the word that you
> hear is not mine but the Father's who sent me.
>
> **25 “These things I have spoken to you while I am still with you. 26
> But the Helper, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my name,
> he will teach you all things and bring to your remembrance all that I
> have said to you.**

"I will ask the Father" - Jesus is asking the father.
"and he will give you another Helper" - the Father will give another Helper
17 "even the Spirit of Truth" - the Helper is the Spirit of Truth

Based on the passage:

1. Jesus is not sending "another comforter" the Father is sending a
   Helper, the Spirit of Truth.
2. Jesus is not speaking in the third
   person.
3. In verse 18-21 Jesus does say that he will come again, but
   that soon he will leave and that they should be obedient while he is gone.
4. In verse 25 Jesus says that the Helper, the Holy Spirit -
   whom the Father will send - will teach them all things and remind
   them of Jesus' commands.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the ‘Holy Spirit’ is used to answer / justify passages depending on the individuals beliefs in the most extraordinary manner. Is Jesus, God, Son of God, HS or a prophet a significant difference.

pneuma is an ancient Greek word for ***breath*** but is used as ‘sprit’ often in the bible.

Without getting bogged down pneuma is used in so many different ways emphasising different points.

The truth of this has been hindered by the doctrine of the Trinity, pursuing pneuma as referring to “God the Holy Spirit” in a majority of the verses, even if the context doesn’t intend that interpretation.

Pneuma is the gift of God – He can give it to some people, give different measures to different people, can take it away from people.

Holy Spirit – is not a person but the breath, wind etc… of God

Mary was pregnant through “the Holy Spirit” [pneuma], Pneuma is used of angels, who are spirit beings, Evil spirits, In Luke 8:55, Jesus raised a little girl from the dead “Her spirit [pneuma] returned,  James 2:26, “…the body without the spirit [pneuma, here referring to the “life”] is dead….”, Jesus received the HS like a Dove [doesn’t imply that Jesus was 2 of the 3 in trinity?],  So on…….

Without getting distracted, less analyse John 14;

Berean Literal Bible – John 14:
16And I will ***ask the Father,*** and He will give you ***another Helper,*** that He may be with you to the age—
26 But the ***Helper,*** the Holy Spirit, whom the Father ***will send*** in My name, ***He will teach you all things*** and will bring to your remembrance all things that I have said to you.
30 No longer will I speak much with you; for the ***ruler of this world comes,*** and in Me he has nothing.

***clearly Jesus is going to ask God to send another helper – not talking about someone already here & HS has been here since the beginning***

Holy Spirit could have taught us before and after Jesus but there is no evidence of any HS teaching us.

***Other evidence backs this up;***

John 15:26 When the ***Helper comes,*** whom I will send to you from the Father, the Spirit of truth who goes forth from the Father, He will bear witness concerning Me.

John 16:7-14 "Nevertheless I tell you the truth; It is expedient for you that ***I go away:*** for if I go not away, the ***Comforter*** will not come unto you; but if I depart, ***I will send him*** unto you. And ***when he is come, he will reprove the world of sin, and of righteousness, and of judgment:*** Of sin, because they believe not on me; Of righteousness, because I go to my Father, and ye see me no more; Of judgment, because the prince of this world is judged. ***I have yet many things to say unto you, but ye cannot bear them now.*** Howbeit when he, the ***Spirit of truth, is come, he will guide you into all truth: for he shall not speak of himself; but whatsoever he shall hear,*** [that] shall he speak: and ***he will shew you things to come.*** He shall glorify me: for he shall receive of mine, and shall shew [it] unto you."

[clearly Jesus is not going to fufill all, but another will come]

John 1:19-27 19 Now this was John’s testimony when the Jewish leaders in Jerusalem sent priests and Levites to ask him who he was. 20 He did not fail to confess, but confessed freely, “I am not the Messiah.” (note this would be Jesus) 21 They asked him, “Then who are you? Are you Elijah?” He said, “I am not.” “Are you the Prophet?”

[clearly talking about 3 people, Jesus, Elijah & the prophet]

Luke 3:16 16 John answered them all, “I baptize you with water. ***But one who is more powerful than I will come,*** the straps of whose sandals I am not worthy to untie. He will baptize you with the Holy Spirit and fire.

[someone to come after – annot be Jesus as he was already here at the time, regardless of Jesus being born before or after JtB]

Mark 1:7 7 And this was his message: ***“After me comes the one more powerful than I,*** the straps of whose sandals I am not worthy to stoop down and untie.

1 John 4:1-3 "Beloved, ***believe not every spirit,*** but try the spirits whether they are of God: because many false prophets are gone out into the world,"

[if spirit = HS then not all are true – can HS not be a true? & evil spsirits is HS evil? How many HS are there?]

Some of the above verses, the word "comforter" is translated from the word "Paraclete" ("Ho Parakletos" in Greek). Parakletos in Greek is interpreted as "an advocate", one who pleads the cause of another, one who councils or advises another from deep concern for the other's welfare (Beacon Bible commentary volume VII, p.168)

original Greek manuscripts speak of a "Holy pneuma." The word pneuma {pnyoo'-mah} is the Greek root word for "spirit." There is no separate word for "Ghost" in the Greek manuscripts, of which there are claimed to be over 24,000 today.

John 14:26 is the only verse of the Bible which associates the Parakletos with the Holy Spirit. But if we were to go back to the "ancient manuscripts" themselves, we would find that they are not all in agreement that the "Parakletos" is the Holy Spirit. For instance, in the famous the Codex Syriacus, written around the fifth century C.E., and discovered in 1812 on Mount Sinai by Mrs.Agnes S. Lewis (and Mrs. Bensley), the text of 14:26 reads; "Paraclete, the Spirit"; and not "Paraclete, the Holy Spirit.".

***Does the Holy Spirit "speak" or "inspire"***
The Greek word translated as "hear" in the Biblical verses ("whatsoever he shall hear, that shall he speak") is the Greek word "akouo" {ak-oo'-o} meaning to perceive sounds. It has, for instance, given us the word "acoustics," the science of sounds. Similarly the verb "to speak" is the Greek verb "laleo" {lal-eh'-o} which has the general meaning "to emit sounds" and the specific meaning "to speak." This verb occurs very frequently in the Greek text of the Gospels. It designates a solemn declaration by Jesus during his preaching (For example Matthew 9:18). Obviously, these verbs require hearing and speech organs in order to facilitate them. There is a distinct difference between someone "inspiring" something and him "speaking" something. So, the Paraclete will "hear" and "speak," not "inspire."

***The Holy Ghost was already with them***
In the above verses we read "if I go not away, the Comforter will not come unto you; but if I depart, I will send him unto you." The comforter cannot be the Holy Ghost because the Holy Ghost (according to the Bible) was "with" them already (and even quite active) long before the coming of Jesus himself and then throughout his ministry. Few example.

Genesis 1:2 "And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness [was] upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters."

1 Samuel 10:10 "And when they came thither to the hill, behold, a company of prophets met him; and the Spirit of God came upon him, and he prophesied among them."

1 Samuel 11:6 "And the Spirit of God came upon Saul when he heard those tidings, and his anger was kindled greatly."

"Then he remembered the days of old, Moses, and his people, saying, where is he that brought them up out of the sea with the shepherd of his flock? where is he that put his holy Spirit within him?" (Isaiah 63:11)

"For he (John the Baptist) shall be great in the sight of the Lord, and shall drink neither wine nor strong drink; and he shall be filled with the Holy Ghost, even from his mother's womb." (Luke 1:15)

"And the angel answered and said unto her, The Holy Ghost shall come upon thee." (Luke 1:35)

"And it came to pass, that, when Elisabeth heard the salutation of Mary, the babe leaped in her womb; and Elisabeth was filled with the Holy Ghost" (Luke 1:41)

"And his father Zacharias was filled with the Holy Ghost, and prophesied, saying," (Luke 1:67)

"And, behold, there was a man in Jerusalem, whose name was Simeon; and the same man was just and devout, waiting for the consolation of Israel: and the Holy Ghost was upon him." (Luke 2:25)

"And it was revealed unto him by the Holy Ghost (Simeon), that he should not see death, before he had seen the Lord's Christ." (Luke 2:26)

"And the Holy Ghost descended in a bodily shape like a dove upon him (Jesus), and a voice came from heaven, which said, Thou art my beloved Son; in thee I am well pleased." (Luke 3:22)

"Then said Jesus to them again, Peace be unto you: as my Father hath sent me, even so send I you. And when he had said this, he breathed on them, and saith unto them, Receive ye the Holy Ghost." (John 20:21-22)

Did they or did they not already receive the Holy Ghost? Was Jesus not still with them when they received the Holy Ghost? Was the Holy Ghost not with Simeon, Mary, Elisabeth and Zacharias before the birth of Jesus? Was the Holy Ghost not with Moses when he parted the seas? There are many more similar verses to be found in the Bible. In the above verses, we are told that if Jesus does not depart then the ***parakletos*** will not come & ***another***. Thus, the "Holy Ghost" cannot be the one originally intended since it was already with them. The contradiction is quite obvious.

***Jesus is also a Paraclete / advocate / comforter***

1 John 2:1 (NRSV) 2 My little children, I am writing these things to you so that you may not sin. But if anyone does sin, we have an advocate (parakletos) with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous;

Matthew 21:11 NRSV) 11 The crowds were saying, “This is the prophet Jesus from Nazareth in Galilee.”

Luke 24:19 (NRSV) 19 He asked them, “What things?” They replied, “The things about Jesus of Nazareth, who was a prophet mighty in deed and word before God and all the people,

***"He" not "It"*** Notice the use of "he" when referring to the Paraclete and not "it." If we read
John 16:13, we will find no less than SEVEN occurrences of the masculine pronoun "He" and "Himself." There is not another verse in the 66 books of the Protestant Bible or the seventy three books of the Catholic Bible which contains seven masculine pronouns, or seven feminine pronouns, or even seven neuter genders. So many masculine pronouns ill befits a ghost, holy or otherwise. The word "Spirit" (Greek, pneu'ma), is of a neutral gender and is always referred to by the pronoun "it."

John 16:13 (NRSV) 13 When the Spirit of truth comes, he will guide you into all the truth; for he will not speak on his own, but will speak whatever he hears, and he will declare to you the things that are to come.

1 John 4:6 (NRSV) 6 We are from God. Whoever knows God listens to us, and whoever is not from God does not listen to us. From this we know the spirit of truth and the spirit of error.

***Conclusion:***

Clearly, without doubt Jesus is talking about another to come.  The ‘comforter’ in this passage is not Jesus and the ‘spirit of truth’ relates to the comforter that is going to come will speak the truth.

Similarly, the below does not relate to Jesus
Deuteronomy 18:18 The Prophet like Moses – see link https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/60730/33268

Comment: The comforter is specifically **another** (*allos*). Since it impossible for **another** to be the first, who is the first given?

Comment: @RevelationLad - the first of what?  Comforter, advocate, prophet, I understand are all the same, many prophets come before and Jesus says he has to go before another comes.

Comment: The first *parakletos*. The word is only used in the Fourth Gospel and First John. It is never used to describe prophets.

Comment: @RevelationLad - so who is the 'first' & whats the point your trying to make?  All im saying is 'another' was to come after Jesus.

Comment: My point is that **another** coming **after** means there must have been one which **preceded** the Spirit of the Truth. Since Jesus is called the *parakletos*, He was the first and the Spirit of the Truth was another. Further the Spirit of Truth is *allos parakletos* which means another of the same kind. Jesus is the Truth and the *parakletos* the Spirit is the Spirit if Truth and *allos parakeltos*.

Comment: @RevelationLad - I got the point there had to be one before not disputed.  Arguable if this passage is talking about 2 or only the one to come after.  In any event 'another' is to come.  As to 'first' need a bit more evidence to prove that Jesus was the first & only or if others came before him, but that doesn't change that 'another' is to come.  ***the more important Q would be who is this 'another' to come after Jesus***

Comment: @RevelationLad by the way 1 John 2:1 - uses 'advocate'  - comforter / advocate if they are not prophets what are they?

Comment: 1 John 2:1 says *parakletos* exactly as in the Gospel. Accordingly Jesus is the *parakletos* and the Spirit of Truth is *allos parakletos*.

Comment: @RevelationLad - OK and? I really don't get what point you are trying to make.  If you are implying that your 'A' is correct, totally disagree with your 'A' IMO your assumptions have no merits.  My 'A' shows clearly backed by other passages there was 'another' to come.  Maybe you would like to share who you think this 'another' was or are you trying to say it was the HS (easy way out as you cant accept 'another' was to come)?

Answer (score -1):

***Yes.  The Risen Jesus is our only advocate/mediator with the Father.***  He is literally at His right hand, sharing his Father's eternal logos(Wisdom/Understanding/Truth) with the children of God through himself.  There simply is no room or need for anyone else.  The Risen Son does it all through himself.

### *For there is one God and **ONE Mediator** between God and men, the Man Christ Jesus,* - 1 Timothy 2:5

Acts 2:33

> Therefore being by the right hand of God exalted, and **having received of the Father the promise of the holy spirit, he hath shed forth this, which ye now see and hear.**

### Who is the Parakletos?

John 14:26

> But the ***Parakletos*** G3875, this holy spirit, whom the Father will send in my name, he shall teach you all things, and bring all things to your remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you.

John 15:26

> But when the ***Parakletos*** G3875 is come, whom I will send unto you from the Father, even this spirit of truth, which proceedeth from the Father, he shall testify of me:

John 16:7

> Nevertheless I tell you the truth; It is expedient for you that I go away: for if I go not away, the ***Parakletos*** G3875 will not come unto you; but if I depart, I will send him unto you.

***There is only a need for 1 parakletos and this is the Risen Son.*** I can say this with confidence because John, the same author of the verse in question, also wrote this verse:

1John 2:2

> My little children, these things write I unto you, that ye sin not. And if any man sin, we have a ***Parakletos*** with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous:

Its important to note that in the 14th chapter of John, Jesus has not been glorified. He is speaking as the human Messiah, NOT the Risen Son in all his the glory of his inheritance. The Risen Son, inherits a glorified body and a spirit consciousness(his holy spirit) that he can now share just as his God and Father shares His Spirit (consciousness) perfectly with him.

The Risen Son is the Vine and we are the branches. The Spirit of God proceeds from the Father and moves through the Son to the rest of the children of God.

The Vine is the only pathway to the Father, and therefore, is the only doorway the Father uses to share with us His Spirit; upgrading our corrupted old spirit seed with the new incorruptible seed by way of the Risen Son who is the seed inside all of us who are born again.

Jesus is the only personified holy spirit within the Spirit of our Father.
In the end, all of the children of Elohim, will inherit a holy spirit, which will be one with the Spirit of the Father. At that time, God will be all in all. There is only 1 eternal consciousness and this is the Spirit of YHWH, the Eternal I AM.

Comment: The *parakletos* is first identified as another (allos) who is the Spirit of the Truth. Since it impossible for **another** to be the first, who is the first and how does one distinguish between the *parakletos* and *allos parakletos*?

Comment: @revelationlad  The comforter that preceded Jesus' holy spirit is himself while on earth. He is speaking to his apostles before his death.  He would not leave them comfortless.  When Jesus spoke those words in John 14:16, he had not been glorified yet.  He did not have the ability to share his spirit of Truth, without limit, to his brethren.  When he is describing this new-other comforter he is talking about the gift of his holy spirit which has not yet received.  There really is no need to read into this.  Remember the 1 Truth is revealed to babes...